# Can a Deform Mesh Be Split Along the X Axis?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I am trying to split a deform body mesh along the x axis in order
to further edit the mesh to use to create another object.In this case
form fitting armor, anyone have any advise ?

When I try to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>R</kbd> , I get a
message that says loop cut does not work well with a deformed mesh.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the only answer, but it appears the [`Knife Tool`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/knife.html) seems to work. If someone with more experience with Blender can give a more complete answer please do so.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can the use the [*Side of Active*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/side_of_active.html#side-of-active) *operator* followed by [*split*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/split.html#selection) to do this.

From the manual page on *Side of Active*:

> With an active vertex, this tool will select all vertices in a
> specified direction. It is similar to the Loop Inner-Region tool in
> that it will fill select faces within its perimeters, however, it is
> determined by direction and not by a closed loop.

So to use this in practice, I used the following steps:

1.I assigned this to a [*Quick Favorite*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/tool_system.html?#quick-favorites) for faster access to the *Side of Active* operator, as it an operator that is only accessible via menu otherwise.

2.Then, in the case of the monkey, I selected a single vertex and pressed <kbd>Q</kbd>*>Quick Favorites>Side of Active* and adjusted the *threshold* until half of the object is selected.

3.Next, press <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>G</kbd> to move the split half away.

---

[image]